# How to download and copy Source Code of Smart Contract on ETHscan that has 8 files listed?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix, etherscan

I am trying to get a verified smart contract that has 8 different files.

Is there a way to download the files together or do you have to copy each separately?

Then how would you you compile these in remix? Would you copy and past each one after the other?

[image]

Im not sure how to get the full code or how to lay it out if i copy each part.

Comment: Can you share the link to the contract in etherscan? I can generate the smart contract for you.